# Rails 5: JavaScript runs but doesn't appear in browser

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, html, canvas, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to run some JavaScript on a canvas element in my Rails 5 application.  My canvas element appears on the appropriate page, but I cannot see the JS.  After ensuring the problem was not with the rails asset pipeline, I added in some console log messages, and when using developer tools, I can see that the JS is running- it initializes and recognizes my canvas element.  I have been able to see the JS run on screen a couple of times, but can't figure out the common element (have ensured that it isn't an issue of clearing cache/cookies).  I am using the JS on my root path and am wondering if paths are somehow the issue?  Many thanks for any advice & wisdom!

```
console.log("This is a test");

var particles = [];
var particleCount = 30;
var maxVelocity = 2;
var targetFPS = 33;

var canvasWidth = 400;
var canvasHeight = 400;

var imageObj = new Image();


imageObj.onload = function() {
    particles.forEach(function(particle) {
            particle.setImage(imageObj);
    });
};

imageObj.src = "http://www.blog.jonnycornwell.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Smoke10.png";

function Particle(context) {
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;

    this.xVelocity = 0;
    this.yVelocity = 0;

    this.radius = 5;

    this.context = context;

    this.draw = function() {

        if(this.image){
            this.context.drawImage(this.image, this.x-128, this.y-128);
            // If the image is being rendered do not draw the circle so break out of the draw function
            return;
        }
        this.context.beginPath();
        this.context.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        this.context.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 255, 255, 1)";
        this.context.fill();
        this.context.closePath();
    };

    this.update = function() {
        this.x += this.xVelocity;
        this.y += this.yVelocity;

        if (this.x >= canvasWidth) {
            this.xVelocity = -this.xVelocity;
            this.x = canvasWidth;
        }

        else if (this.x <= 0) {
            this.xVelocity = -this.xVelocity;
            this.x = 0;
        }

        if (this.y >= canvasHeight) {
            this.yVelocity = -this.yVelocity;
            this.y = canvasHeight;
        }

        else if (this.y <= 0) {
            this.yVelocity = -this.yVelocity;
            this.y = 0;
        }
    };

    this.setPosition = function(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    };

    this.setVelocity = function(x, y) {
        this.xVelocity = x;
        this.yVelocity = y;
    };

    this.setImage = function(image){
        this.image = image;
    }
}

function generateRandom(min, max){
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

var context;

function init() {
    console.log("in init")
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    console.log("canvas: " + canvas)
    if (canvas.getContext) {

        context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        for(var i=0; i < particleCount; ++i){
            var particle = new Particle(context);

            particle.setPosition(generateRandom(0, canvasWidth), generateRandom(0, canvasHeight));

            particle.setVelocity(generateRandom(-maxVelocity, maxVelocity), generateRandom(-maxVelocity, maxVelocity));
            particles.push(particle);
        }
    }
    else {
        alert("Please use a modern browser");
    }
}

function draw() {
    // Clear the drawing surface and fill it with a black background
    context.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 400);

    // Go through all of the particles and draw them.
    particles.forEach(function(particle) {
        particle.draw();
    });
}

function update() {
    particles.forEach(function(particle) {
        particle.update();
    });
}


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event){
  console.log("gets to init")
  init();
});

if (context) {
    setInterval(function() {
        // Update the scene befoe drawing
        update();

        // Draw the scene
        draw();
    }, 1000 / targetFPS);
}
```

HTML

```
 <% content_for :head do %>
   <%= javascript_include_tag "home.js" %>
 <% end %>

<body>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400">
 </canvas>


</body>
</html>
```

Rails route

```
  root to: 'products#home', as: "root"
```

Thanks again!

Comment: If you are using turbolinks adding different scripts to be loaded on different pages by script tags is not a viable solution. Instead you want to write a idempotent javascript function and link to the turbolinks load event. https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#making-transformations-idempotent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one of the following:

Coffescript

```
$(document).on 'ready page:load', ->
  ...your code goes here...
```

Javascript (per request)

```
var ready = function() {
   ... your init code...
};
$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

**OR**

```
$(document).on('ready page:load', function () {
   ...your code goes here...
});
```

Using Turbolinks

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  ...your code goes here...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the turbolinks load function? Just wrap all the Js in the below code:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(){
```